# NullPointerException when getting an intent from other Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having an error while trying to get an intent from another application. At start, I had the intent to run the IP camera stream, and it worked like a charm. But later when I click on the screen to get a snapshot, click yes to share and then cancel the sharing intent to go back to the IP camera stream, I get an error there NullPointerException.

Here is my code:

```
public class Activity_streamCam extends Activity {
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
Activity activity;
final Context context = this;
URL url_snap;
private static final String TAG = "MJPEG";
PowerManager powerManager = null;
WakeLock wakeLock = null;
String URL1, test, URL2;

private boolean suspending = false;

private MjpegView mv;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.stream_camera);
    this.powerManager = (PowerManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    this.wakeLock = this.powerManager.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // URL1 = intent.getExtras().getString("key");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        URL1 = extras.getString("key");
        // Check for presence of URL1
        if (URL1 != null) {
            test = URL1 + "axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240";
        }
    }

    mv = (MjpegView) findViewById(R.id.mv);
    new DoRead().execute(test);

    mv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            try {
                url_snap = new URL(
                        "http://plazacam.studentaffairs.duke.edu/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=320x240");

                Bitmap bmp = snapShotManager.takeSnapshot(url_snap);
                final File share = snapShotManager.saveSnap(bmp);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Success snapshot");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Would you like to share it ?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        mv.stopPlayback();
                                        mv.destroyDrawingCache();
                                        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(
                                                Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                        sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                                        sendIntent.putExtra(
                                                Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri
                                                        .parse("file://"
                                                                + share));
                                        sendIntent
                                                .putExtra(
                                                        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                                        "This snapshot was taken by DroidCamViewer app, check it out ! :)");

                                        try {
                                            startActivity(Intent
                                                    .createChooser(
                                                            sendIntent,
                                                            "share"));
                                        } catch (Exception e) {




                                        }

                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();

                                    }
                                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                alertDialog.show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(getString(R.string.logTag), "Snap I/O exception !!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

}

public void onResume() {
    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume()");

    super.onResume();

    if (mv != null) {
        if (suspending) {
            suspending = false;
            new RestartApp().execute();
            this.wakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }

}

public void onStart() {
    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");
    super.onStart();
}

public void onPause() {

    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause()");
    super.onPause();

}

public void onStop() {
    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop()");
    super.onStop();

}

public void onRestart() {

    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestart()");

    super.onRestart();
    if (mv != null) {
        if (suspending) {
            suspending = false;
            new RestartApp().execute();
            this.wakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
    mv.stopPlayback();
    mv.destroyDrawingCache();
}

public class DoRead extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MjpegInputStream> {
    protected MjpegInputStream doInBackground(String... url) {

        HttpResponse res = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5 * 1000);
        Log.d(TAG, "1. Sending http request");
        try {
            res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url[0])));
            Log.d(TAG, "2. Request finished, status = "
                    + res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            if (res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 401) {

                return null;
            }
            return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-ClientProtocolException", e);
            // Error connecting to camera
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-IOException", e);
            // Error connecting to camera
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MjpegInputStream result) {

        mv.setSource(result);
        if (result != null)
            result.setSkip(1);
        mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
        mv.showFps(true);

    }
}

public class RestartApp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        Activity_streamCam.this.finish();
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        startActivity((new Intent(Activity_streamCam.this,
                Activity_streamCam.class)));
    }
}


    }
```

The NullPointerException results when I click yes on the alert box and then cancel the intent or share the bitmap to go back to the stream.

Here is my logcat

```
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity     ComponentInfo{com.marwen.droidcamviewer/com.marwen.droidcamviewer.Activity_streamCam}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     Method)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at     com.marwen.droidcamviewer.Activity_streamCam.onCreate(Activity_streamCam.java:66)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-13 13:23:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.marwen.droidcamviewer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.marwen.droidcamviewer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_setPreference"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Activity_streamCam"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_streamCam"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Activity_addCam"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_addCam" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Activity_about"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Activity_Camera_list"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="EditCam"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_EditCam" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Activity_manageCam"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_manageCam" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is line 66 in Activity_streamCam.java? That's the line causing the NPE

Comment: `URL1 = intent.getExtras().getString("key");` is the line causing the NPE. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you've got an `Intent` without extras. When you do this:

```
URL1 = intent.getExtras().getString("key");
```

You will get a `NullPointerException` if the `Intent` has no extras.

To prevent this, do:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    URL1 = extras.getString("key");
    // Check for presence of URL1
    if (URL1 != null) {
        // Here you can be sure not to get NullPointerException
    }
}
```

This is just good defensive programming.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Now after I have used your solution, I don't get any NPE errors, but I still cannot resume the streaming after canceling the share intent. Propably I didn't explain well my problem, I used to get the NPE when trying to resume the  Activity_streamCam after taking a snapshot, accept to share it via share intent and then cancel the new dialog that appears to choose one method  to share (E mail, ..).  But before taking the snapshot, It works fine, I'm getting the intent from another class and the stream is okey.

Comment: As you can see above in the manifest, I'm getting the intent from the Activity_Camera_list (the address of the IP camera) to get a use of it in the Activity_streamCam.

Comment: OK, the manifest isn't the problem. What I don't understand is why `onCreate()` is being called when you return to your activity after canceling the share. This shouldn't happen. Normally, if you cancel the share, it should just return to your activity and call `onResume()`. I'm guessing that somehow you are recreating your activity when the share is canceled. You should step through this with a debugger (or add a lot of debug logging in the lifecycle methods) and see what happens after you cancel the share. What are you doing in `onPause()` of your activity? because that will be called

Comment: I thought about that aswell, I have edited and pasted my whole activity above.

Comment: Your `RestartApp` is calling `finish()` on `Activity_streamCam` and then restarting it like this: `startActivity((new Intent(Activity_streamCam.this, Activity_streamCam.class)));`. This is why `onCreate()` is getting called again and also why it has an `Intent` without extras!

Comment: Ah yes, now I understand. What shall I do to fix it please ? I'm using that method for the onResume and onRestart. I'm stuck and I'm just a beginner in Android. Sorry if I'm asking too much.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you set `suspending` to `true`. Please explain where/why this is set and when/why you are restarting the Activity.

Comment: `suspending` is used in another class in `startPlayback()` `resumePlayback()` and `stopPlayback()`. Restarting activity will occur in `onResume()` and `onRestart()`.

Comment: SOrry, I don't know enough about your application or its architecture to help you with this. You need to post more code and/or explain more about what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I'm new to the Android field so I cannot explain more about it. I'm using this open source code found [here](http://www.imsmart.com/blocks/action.jsp?blockId=3782&key=8a2993d23e8e0a85013e9d2d335e0957) and trying to learn from it. I have added some methods that you will find them in the code pasted above. Thank you for your attention.